# Pattern for using two implementations of one class if no common interface available

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

Imagine we have some interface. We need to use two different implementations of this interface. The implementations exist. But there is a problem: the implementations do not *formally* implement that interface. Thats because they are in fact two independent products and they cannot be adjusted with our interfaces.

I.e.

```
interface Action {
void doAction();
}

class ActionFirstImpl {
void doAction() {
...
}
}

class ActionSecondImpl {
void doAction() {
...
}
}
```

What is the best way to use these implementations in our project?
The only thing I can imagine is to create two intermediate classes which implement this interface and subclass this class from the implementations provided. 
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't *subclass* the implementation classes. I'd just use the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) and *delegate* to the implementation classes:

```
public final class ActionFirstImplAdapter implements Action {
    private final ActionFirstImpl delegate;

    public ActionFirstImplAdapter(ActionFirstImpl delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void doAction() {
        delegate.doAction();
    }
}
```

... and exactly the same for the `ActionSecondImpl`.

Normally the adapter pattern requires a bit more adaptation than just "delegate to a method with the exact same signature" but it still works in that simple case too.

Comment: @nachokk: Added the @Override; not sure what you mean by "also saying that is object adapter version".

Comment: [object adapter](http://i.imgur.com/XeZA2rp.png) and [class adapter](http://i.imgur.com/s9FxW8Q.png) uml

Comment: @nachokk: I reckon it's clear enough by the name - and the documentation can clarify further.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [delegation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_%28programming%29) (i.e. the [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)):

```
class ActionImplementingClass implements Action {

    private ActionFirstImpl data;

    // ...

    @Override
    public void doAction() {
        data.doAction();
    }

}
```

The same can be done with `ActionSecondImpl`.